# What does Shift-Command-Space keyboard shortcut do?

Tags: macos, shortcut

Apple's macOS Human Interface Guidelines [shows](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/user-interaction/keyboard/) that action for the Shift-Command-Space keyboard shortcut is: Varies. Apple Reserved.

**Does that mean that Apple is reserving it for future use?**

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On my iMac, running macOS High Sierra, it does nothing. Go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts tab. This will list all the system defined and custom keyboard shortcuts. If there is something that you want <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> to do, you can define it here.

I just set <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> to **Show Launchpad**, and it works fine. So it appears that the key combination is currently unassigned.-

The image below shows where I defined <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>:

[image]